# SQL queries without specific inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sometimes my coworkers give me queries written like this:

```
SEL c.col1, b.col2, a.somecol, a.somemore
FROM db.tbl1 A, db.tbl2 B, db.tbl3 C
WHERE A.id = B.id and B.otherId = C.otherID
GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1
```

I just wanted to clarify what this actually means.  Is it the same thing as this:

```
SELECT
  c.col1
  b.col2
  a.somecol
  a.somemore
FROM
  db.tbl1 AS A
INNER JOIN db.tbl2 AS B
  ON B.id = A.id
INNER JOIN db.tbl3 AS C
  ON C.otherId = B.otherID
GROUP BY
  c.col1,
  b.col2
ORDER BY
  c.col1
```

I'm just trying to make things more clear and readible, but wanted to make sure I wasn't misinterpreting anything from a performance standpoint or something.  I'm also replacing the aliases with more legible names, etc...

Comment: Yes. Except SQL Server does not support group by column ordinal anyway. `Ansi 89` vs `Ansi 92` syntax. Plenty of dupes for that part of the question.

Comment: It's just an old school way of doing joins, I have no idea what those group bys are doing though.

Comment: Ok great, thanks guys.  That's what I suspected, and the results are the same... just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else stated there are no benefits one way or the other, but that is incorrect. There are benefits to using explicit joins. There are no benefits to using implicit joins unless your database is so old it won't use explicit joins.

Many accidental cross joins are prevented by using explicit joins.

Intent is clear when you actually want a cross join.

Implicit joins are harder to maintain especially if you need to change to a left join as mixing the two (and some databases do not support a left join syntax that is implicit) will often result incorrect results.

Unless you are working on a database that is such an old version it only takes implicit joins, it is a bad choice to ever write one more than 20 years after something better came out. I see any and they fail code review. Implicit joins are a SQL anti-pattern and there is no excuse to use one if you use a modern database.

Answer (score 1):

That is the same as JOIN.

SQL was standardized in 1986 but didn't have JOIN until the 3rd revision in 1992.

As the commenters said, I have no idea what the GROUP BY's are doing. They're used with aggregates.

Answer (score -1):

They are writing IMPLICIT JOINS and you are writing EXPLICIT JOINS. For decades ANSI consortium is trying to put that implicit joins in a deprecated black list but there are many legacy system (and legacy programmers).
There's no benefits in one or another form beyond explicit joins are more readable. In some places you ill find documentation telling joins precedes where clauses but the true is engine can rearrange it behind the curtain.

Comment: AFAIK no one has tried to deprecate ANSI 89 inner joins, Joe Celko (who was on the standards committee) claims that [Weaker SQL programmers use INNER JOIN, since it is sequential and a familiar, procedural infix binary operator. Stronger SQL programmers use the WHERE syntax because it is set-oriented, obeys the law of proximity and is an n-ary operator.](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=162162) I don't agree!

Comment: AFAIK, Celko don't speaks for the commite and i know that guy from forums for years and he is a great pro and academic but is also a legacy programmer.